# Set bounds of locations search by Google GeoCoding API in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geocoding

Everyone
I am trying to do something with MKMapView. I have a location in form of latitude and longitude value and I want to search for annotations present in 200km around this location using google geocoding API. Can anyone please tell me how to set this bound? 
I am currently using following url to send my location to google geocoding api.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the google key only you can able to access this link. try to get the key from google.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=200&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=(Here you can use your key).

Comment: This Places API is limitted to 1000 queries/day